# While loop and expected output in python

Tags: python, numpy, while-loop

I have defined image data shape (160,160,160) and original data is of shape (7,). Aim is to calculate RMSE first and then update the sigma value untill RMSE equal or less then one. want to know sigma value that is correspond to RMSE equal or less then one. 
I tried this script but it does not iterate or update sigma value in WHILE LOOP. I might missed something here.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
img = (np.ones((160,160,160)))
orig_data = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())
sigma = 5
filt_img = gaussian_filter(img, sigma)
C = filt_img[80,:,80]
D = C[np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])]
rmse_val = rmse(D,orig_data)
delta = 0.2
while rmse_val <= 1:
    sigma += delta
    filt_img = gaussian_filter(img, sigma)
    C = filt_img[80,:,80]
    D = C[np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])]
    rmse_val = rmse(D,orig_data)
print("rms error is: " + str(rmse_val))
print('sigma:', sigma)
```

Comment: In addition to what the other answer says, for easy debugging you can add print statements in your loop to see if your code even enters the loop.

Comment: yes code enters the loop .

Answer (score 1):

Running your code shows that `rmse_val = 5.385` which is not `<= 1` therefore your code never enters the while loop and so `sigma` is not updated

Comment: thanks for reply. I would like to have RMSE value close to zero and to know corresponding sigma value that can provide RMSE value. you mean while condition should be changes ?

Comment: since your aim is `RMSE <= 1` change the condition to `rmse_val > 1` and once it breaks the loop your aim will be achieved

Comment: @kssoklall, it never ends when condition changed to rmse_val > 1. any way code enters the loop. any suggestion ?

Comment: your code only outputs `5.385164807134504` most of the time. You can see this by printing the output and watching it. You will need to fix your formula.

Comment: @Python if your code never ends the issue is your function isn't converging. According to ^^ it's at 5.38 most of the time

Comment: @ksooklall thanks for your reply. But incase i consider data img = np.array([33,94,55,86,47,81,29])
orig_data = np.array([38,45,15,6,37,18,19]) code shows multiple outputs. But I am interessted  one with lowest RMSE among those outcome values. Any idea to achieve goal?.

Comment: what do you mean by lowest? Your quest has rmse_val <= 1, if you mean lowest as above 0 then `rmse_val > 0`

Comment: @ksoolall, I created sample data as you see in above example. But if I apply same script on my original data RMSE varies with sigma value. First start from large value to lowest value and then increase again. in that situation I want to extract lowest value and correspond sigma value.

Comment: collect them all in a list and then get the lowest with `min(rmse_lst)`, or better a dict with `{'rmse': [], 'other_val: []}`

Answer (score 0):

Code works. The reason code never enters loop because of while condition was not correctly defined.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
img = (np.ones((160,160,160)))
orig_data = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
def rmse(predictions, targets):
    return np.sqrt(((predictions - targets) ** 2).mean())
sigma = 5
filt_img = gaussian_filter(img, sigma)
C = filt_img[80,:,80]
D = C[np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])]
rmse_val = rmse(D,orig_data)
delta = 0.2
while rmse_val > 1:
    sigma += delta
    filt_img = gaussian_filter(img, sigma)
    C = filt_img[80,:,80]
    D = C[np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])]
    rmse_val = rmse(D,orig_data)
print("rms error is: " + str(rmse_val))
print('sigma:', sigma)
```